# How to make a delete confirmation that need a minimum of 1 record to be deleted?

Tags: php, javascript

I need help on making a delete confirmation that need a minimum of 1 record to be deleted.
I'm still confused on making it. I think there's something wrong in my javascript code. Any help would much be appreciated. Thanks

here's the php code:

```
enter code here

<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php
echo"<form method=POST action='action.php?act=delete'>
     <input type=checkbox name='checkbox[]' value='1'>1
     <input type=checkbox name='checkbox[]' value='2'>2
     <input type=checkbox name='checkbox[]' value='3'>3
     <input type=submit value=Delete onClick='return del_confirm();'></form>";
?>
```

here's the javascript code:

```
enter code here

function del_confirm()
{
var msg=confirm('Are you sure?');
var c=document.getElementsByName('checkbox[]');
if(msg)
{
    for(i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
    if(c[i].checked)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Select minimum of 1 record to be deleted!");
        return false;
    }
    }
}
else
{return false;}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off:

```
function del_confirm() {
    var msg = confirm('Are you sure?');
    var c = document.getElementsByName('checkbox[]');
    if(msg) {
        for(i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i].checked) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // This has to be outside the for loop,
        // that way it only gets here if every box is not checked
        alert("Select minimum of 1 record to be deleted!");
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}​
```

You had the alert inside the for loop so the first unchecked box returned false for the function.

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FfkvW/